# Extract node value for Oracle Clob

Tags: xml, oracle, clob

I have a CLOB column which has XML-style data in it, though it certainly doesn't appear to have parent-child node relationships; it looks like this:

```
<servicePointExternalId>8629391888</servicePointExternalId><externalSPType>E-M-COM</externalSPType><faType>M-STARTS</faType><requesterUserId>E05920</requesterUserId><replyToExternalSystem>D1YS</replyToExternalSystem><externalReferenceId>47676141503102</externalReferenceId><retryDetails><numberOfRetries>0</numberOfRetries><isToDoEntrySuppressed>false</isToDoEntrySuppressed><retryDateTime>2017-04-28-18.16.53</retryDateTime><currentErrorState>VALERROR</currentErrorState></retryDetails><contactDetails><customerName>Hofstader, Leonard</customerName><contactName>Hofstader, Leonard</contactName><accountId>5669202300</accountId><personId>9538791588</personId></contactDetails><saList><eventType>D1ST</eventType><saId>5668577181</saId></saList>
```

I am trying to just extract the `requesteruserID` value (which should be E05920) from this field and I am getting this error message:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 1
LPX-00245: extra data after end of document
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample is not a full XML document - it has no parent node, just adjacent child nodes.

If you want to treat it as XML you need to wrap it in a dummy root node, e.g. if your CLOB is in a column called `clob_col` you can do:

```
xmltype(to_clob('<root>') || clob_col || '</root>')
```

To get the specific node value you want you can then do:

```
select xmlquery(
  '/root/requesterUserId/text()'
  passing xmltype(to_clob('<root>') || clob_col || '</root>')
  returning content) as result
from your_table;

RESULT                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E05920
```

Or with the table and column name you've added as a comment:

```
select xmlquery(
  '/root/requesterUserId/text()'
  passing xmltype(to_clob('<root>') || A.BO_DATA_AREA || '</root>')
  returning content) as result
from CISADM.D1_ACTIVITY A
```

or just

```
select xmlquery(
  '/root/requesterUserId/text()'
  passing xmltype('<root>' || A.BO_DATA_AREA || '</root>')
  returning content) as result
from CISADM.D1_ACTIVITY A
```

You can cast the XML fragment that returns to another data type:

```
select cast(
  xmlquery( '/root/requesterUserId/text()'
    passing xmltype(to_clob('<root>') || A.BO_DATA_AREA|| '</root>')
    returning content)
  as varchar2(8)) as requesterUserId
from CISADM.D1_ACTIVITY A;
```

or as an alternative you can use [XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm#SQLRF06232) instead of [XMLQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions265.htm#SQLRF06209):

```
select x.requesterUserId
from CISADM.D1_ACTIVITY A
cross join xmltable(
  '/root'
  passing xmltype('<root>' || A.BO_DATA_AREA || '</root>')
  columns requesterUserId varchar2(8) path 'requesterUserId'
) x;
```

either of which gives a plain string value:

```
REQUESTE
--------
E05920
```

[Read more about XML processing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB1700).

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, based on your answer, this is what my code should look like.                                                                         
      select  xmlquery(
  '/root/requesterUserId/text()'
  passing xmltype(A.BO_DATA_AREA('<root>') || A.BO_DATA_AREA|| '</root>')
  returning content) as result
from CISADM.D1_ACTIVITY A;                                                                          I am still getting this error though: ORA-00904: "A"."BO_DATA_AREA": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: You've mangled that a bit; `A.BO_DATA_AREA('<root>')` should be `to_clob('<root>')`. (The `to_clob()` is to make sure the first argument for the concatenation operator is a `clob`, [though that isn't really necessary](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/operators003.htm#SQLRF51158).)

Comment: Ahh, shoot, sorry I was thinking that you meant TO_CLOB as a place holder for the actual column, sorry for the mistake.  It seems to generate the same error, regardless

ORA-00904: "TO_CLOB": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Thinking its a column or something? Hey thanks for the quick answers by the way - really appreciate the help!

Comment: It's a function, not a column, no idea why that wouldn't be available? You don't need it though, just can just use the plain string.

Comment: This is definitely getting closer - i finally have it running successfully, but it returns to me a column called "Result" and the value is (XMLTYPE) instead of the actual value coming out of the clob.

Comment: @JordanHaymond - in the result window grid in SQL Developer? You can make it display the full value from Tools->Preferences->Database->Advanced->Display XML Value In Grid; or double-click on the (XMLTYPE) cell to reveal its value; or right click and choose single record view. I've added two ways to get the value as plain text though.

Comment: Awesome! Totally solved my issue, thanks so much for being patient and providing awesome resources. Can't thank you enough!